# R question: How to solve lme4 "Error in .empty.factors(e1) : object 'R_empty_factors' not found"

Tags: r, lme4

I have an R script that has worked fine up until today, but now I cannot run any `lme4` models. If, for example, I try to run the model from the `lme4` example data:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in .empty.factors(e1) : object 'R_empty_factors' not found
```

This happens for any `lme4` model that I try to fit. The package loads fine. I've also tried re-installing `lme4`, but this didn't solve it. Other packages in R seem to work fine (e.g., `dplyr`)

I've also tried Googling this particular error and haven't found anything. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Is some old workspace loaded? Is your global environment empty? Which other packages are loaded? Try using `lme4::lmer` to ensure that the function isn't masked somehow.

Comment: @Roland I've tried clearing the R environment using rm(list=ls()) and restarting the R session, then just loading lme4 and trying to fit a model and I get this error.
I also tried with lme4::lmer, but it gives the same response